# Android - ActionBarSherlock - Set textcolor of text in submenu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, submenu, textcolor

How can i set the color of text in submenu of Action Bar Sherlock ? I can set the background but not the textcolor.. =(

temas.xml

```
<style name="Tema.Laranja" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">

    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/background_selecionado</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/background_selecionado</item>

    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Tema.Laranja.ListSelector</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Tema.Laranja.ListSelector</item>

    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Tema.Laranja.Popup</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/Tema.Laranja.Popup</item>
</style>

    <style name="Tema.Laranja.Popup" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/shape_laranja_arredondado</item>
</style>

<style name="Tema.Laranja.ListSelector" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@color/listview_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/branca</item>
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
</style>
```

My listview_actionbar.xml

```
<item android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/shape_amarelo_arredondado"/>

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/shape_amarelo_arredondado" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/shape_amarelo_arredondado" />

<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/shape_amarelo_arredondado" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/shape_amarelo_arredondado" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/shape_amarelo_arredondado" />
```

Comment: I've tried both answers, neither worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/dropdown_selector</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu" parent="Widget">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/branco</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">
    <!-- @style/some style that has android:textColor as attribute -->
</item> <!-- in Tema.Laranja style -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use actionBarWidgetTheme and android:textColor.

Example:

```
<style name="Theme.Guide" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBar.Widget.Guide</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBar.Widget.Guide</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Widget.Guide" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/action_bar_dropdown_menu_text_size</item>
</style>
```